# Using wp_insert_post to create custom posts with ACF image field

Tags: custom-post-types, images, wp-insert-post

I've been searching for an answer for days now.
I have a project where I need to create a front-end form that will request a bunch of information and use it to create a post draft for the client to approve or not on the admin panel. So far I was able to create a shortcode to show the HTML form on the front-end, get the information needed and create the draft on my custom post type. The biggest issue is uploading images, I can't seem to make it work, or even find a solution anywhere.

This is my current code:

```
add_action ( 'init', 'create_cpt_teste');

function create_cpt_teste() {
    register_post_type ('cpt-teste',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'CPT Teste',
                'singular_name' => 'CPT Teste',
                'add_new' => 'Adicionar Novo',
                'add_new_item' => 'Adicionar Novo CPT Teste',
                'edit' => 'Editar',
                'edit_item' => 'Editar CPT Teste',
                'new_item' => 'Novo CPT Teste',
                'view' => 'Visualizar',
                'view_item' => 'Visualizar CPT Teste',
                'search_items' => 'Pesquisar CPT Teste',
                'not_found' => 'Nenhum CPT Teste Encontrado',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nenhum CPT Teste Encontrado na Lixeira',
                'parent' => 'CPT Teste Superior'
            ),

            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'cpt-teste' ),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 25,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-store'
        )
    );
}

function zmg_form() {
    ?>
    <form id="teste-cpt" name="teste-cpt" method="post" action="">
        <p>
            <label for="nome">Nome</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="nome" value="" size="20" name="nome" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="teste1">Teste 1</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="teste1" value="" size="20" name="teste1" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="teste2">Teste 2</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="teste2" value="" size="20" name="teste2" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="teste3">Teste 3</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="teste3" value="" size="20" name="teste3" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="teste-dropdown">Teste Dropdown</label><br />
            <select name="teste-dropdown">
                <option value="Drop1">Drop1</option>
                <option value="Drop2">Drop2</option>
                <option value="Drop3">Drop3</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="foto01">Foto 01</label><br />
            <input type="file" id="foto01" name="foto01" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="foto02">Foto 02</label><br />
            <input type="file" id="foto02" name="foto02" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="submit" name="submit" />
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="post-type" id="post-type" value="cpt-teste" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="cpt-teste" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field ( 'name_of_my_action','name_of_nonce_field') ?>
    </form>

    <?php
    if($_POST) {
        zmg_save_post_data();
    }

}

add_shortcode('teste-form','zmg_form');

function zmg_save_post_data() {
    if ( empty($_POST) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['name_of_nonce_field'],'name_of_my_action') )
    {
        print 'Desculpe, o nonce não foi verificado.';
        exit;
    } else {
        //Validações
        if (isset ($_POST['nome'])) {
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        } else {
            echo 'Por favor, preencha o nome.';
            exit;
        }
        if (isset ($_POST['teste1'])) {
            $teste1 = $_POST['teste1'];
        } else {
            echo 'Por favor, preencha o teste1.';
            exit;
        }
        if (isset ($_POST['teste2'])) {
            $teste2 = $_POST['teste2'];
        } else {
            echo 'Por favor, preencha o teste2.';
            exit;
        }
        if (isset ($_POST['teste3'])) {
            $teste3 = $_POST['teste3'];
        } else {
            echo 'Por favor, preencha o teste3.';
            exit;
        }
        if (isset ($_POST['teste-dropdown'])) {
            $testedropdown = $_POST['teste-dropdown'];
        } else {
            echo 'Por favor, preencha o teste-dropdown.';
            exit;
        }
        if (isset ($_POST['foto01'])) {
            $foto01 = $_POST['foto01'];
        } else {
            echo 'Por favor, selecione a foto 01.';
            exit;
        }
        if (isset ($_POST['foto02'])) {
            $foto02 = $_POST['foto02'];
        } else {
            echo 'Por favor, selecione a foto 02.';
            exit;
        }


        //Colocando conteúdos no array
        $post_info = array(
            'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $nome ),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'draft',
            'post_type' => 'cpt-teste',
        );

        $postID = wp_insert_post( $post_info, true );

        update_field('field_59b0072b00b03', $teste1, $postID);
        update_field('field_59b0073e00b04', $teste2, $postID);
        update_field('field_59b0074d00b05', $teste3, $postID);
        update_field('field_59b0075b00b06', $testedropdown, $postID);
        update_field('field_59b023839f5fc', $foto01, $postID);
        update_field('field_59b023ca9f5fe', $foto02, $postID);


        $location = home_url();

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=$location' />";
        exit;
    }
}
```

The text fields work just fine, my problem is with the images.

Comment: if it was wordpress apis it would have been "simple", you need to creat an attachment out of the uploaded file. As it is ACF specific it is off-topic what additional steps might be required to play well with ACF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACF has documentation for creating a form on the frontend.  I would stick to their suggestions.  https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/

I was able to create this by assigning my field group for the form to the custom post type and using a unique template page for the form.

```
<?php
/**
  * Template Name: Form Page Template
  */
 ?> 

<?php acf_form_head(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php acf_form(array(
                'post_id'       => 'new_post',
                'new_post'      => array(
                    'post_type'     => 'cpt-teste',
                    'post_status'   => 'draft'
                ),
                'submit_value'  => 'Submit'
            )); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I read that earlier today, wasn't much help. But I'll run some more tests, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I updated my answer.  You wouldn't be able to incorporate this in a shortcode.  Try creating a unique page for the form.

Comment: I will try this! Later today I'll come back here and tell you about the outcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @finitesource ! It took a little tweaking, but in the end worked like a charm!